# Bootstrap 4 grid, колоночная верстка col md offset и прочее

Tags: вёрстка, bootstrap4, grid

Всем привет, это мой первый вопрос на стуковерфлоу, и так, я изучаю верстку с помощью bootstrap 4 , и там используется технология grid, мой ментор каким-то волшебным образом когда создает контейнер располагает все с помощью col md и значения, я конечно понимаю что вот 12 колонок есть все содержится внутри них и соответственно располагается, но я немного не понимаю как это работает, вся документация Bootstrapa на англ, а английский у меня но соу перфект чтобы понимать  все, прошу обьясните на доступном языке как это работает.
Ps у меня хорошее настроение сегодня, просьба, у людей с плохим настроением/чувства юмора, не обращать внимание на юмористический подтекст.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, сконцентрируйтесь на проблеме в тектсе вопроса. В вопрос не нужно вставлять приветствия и подписи с наилучшими пожеланиями. Так же приведите код в котором пытаетесь разобраться https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: ну там не совсем гриды применяются....типа псевдо-гриды. На текущий момент лучше изучать нормальную грид-систему (возможно бутстрап 5 перейдет на гриды сам)

Comment: @АлексДанилин к сожалению мне нужно это знать, как создавать по макеты секции, а внутри контейнер с row и colами